# Getting the final form the HTML body with WebBrowser?

Tags: c#

When using .NET's WebBrowser control, how can I get the entire HTML of the document after all ajax and the like is executed?

I'm trying to navigate a site that actually loads its ENTIRE body with an onLoad event in the body tag..and I am unable to access any of the form elements in it because they aren't initially loaded (even though visibly they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that on the DocumentCompleted event, the data is completely received, but onLoad events are not tripped. The solution is to wait until AFTER the DocumentCompleted event has fired, and THEN get the innerHTML.